# Change checkbox icon in theme

Tags: material-ui, themes

Is it possible to change the icon of the checkbox from the theme in Material UI?

```
props: {
        MuiButtonBase: {
            disableRipple: buttonRippleDisable
        },
        MuiButton: {
            disableElevation: buttonElevationDisable
        },
        MuiCheckbox: {
            icon: CheckCircleOutline,
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. pass the icon in `props` object in theme as you've done above.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    props:{
        MuiCheckbox:{
            icon: <FavoriteBorder />,
            checkedIcon:<Favorite />
        }
    }
});
```

Now wherever you use the checkbox in the scope of this theme, you'll get this icon by default.

Working demo:
[image: Edit empty-fog-wjvnr]

Comment: Huh, I could swear I've tried that... oh well, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In MUI v5

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    components: {
        MuiCheckbox: {
            defaultProps: {
                icon: {YOUR ICON},
                checkedIcon: {YOUR ICON}
            }
           
        }
    }
});
```